# Google Guava: How to use ImmutableSortedMap.naturalOrder?

Tags: java, syntax, guava

I'm using Google Guava r08 and JDK 1.6.0_23.

I want to create an `ImmutableSortedMap` using a builder. I know I can create the builder like this:

```
ImmutableSortedMap.Builder<Integer, String> b1 =
    new ImmutableSortedMap.Builder<Integer, String>(Ordering.natural());
```

and then use that to build maps, for example:

```
ImmutableSortedMap<Integer, String> map =
    b1.put(1, "one").put(2, "two").put(3, "three").build();
```

I noticed that class `ImmutableSortedMap` has a method `naturalOrder()` that returns a `Builder` with natural ordering. However, when I try to call this method, I get strange errors. For example, this gives a strange "; expected" error:

```
// Does not compile
ImmutableSortedMap.Builder<Integer, String> b2 =
    ImmutableSortedMap<Integer, String>.naturalOrder();
```

What is the correct syntax to call the `naturalOrder()` method?

The API documentation of the method mentions some compiler bug. Does that have anything to do with this method not working?

**edit**

MForster's answer is good. But when leaving off the generics, I can't do it "in one go":

```
// Doesn't work, can't infer the types properly
ImmutableSortedMap<Integer, String> map =
    ImmutableSortedMap.naturalOrder().put(1, "one").put(2, "two").put(3, "three").build();
```

This does work:

```
ImmutableSortedMap<Integer, String> map =
    ImmutableSortedMap.<Integer, String>naturalOrder().put(1, "one").put(2, "two").put(3, "three").build();
```

Comment: Yes, if you build the whole map in one series of chained calls, you do have to put `ImmutableSortedMap.<Integer, String>naturalOrder()`. Java is unable to infer the type arguments of the `naturalOrder()` call since the `Builder` it returns isn't ever assigned to anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
ImmutableSortedMap.Builder<Integer, String> b2 =
    ImmutableSortedMap.<Integer, String>naturalOrder();
```

And you can drop the generics altogether, because they are inferred in this case:

```
ImmutableSortedMap.Builder<Integer, String> b2 =
    ImmutableSortedMap.naturalOrder();
```

Comment: Ah, it's that simple! Thanks.

Comment: More information about the "ImmutableSortedMap.<Integer, String>naturalOrder()" syntax: 
http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ402 (explicit type argument specification)

Answer (score 5):

The correct syntax should be:

```
ImmutableSortedMap.Builder<Integer, String> b2 =
ImmutableSortedMap.<Integer, String>naturalOrder();
```

(Note that the generic parameters are behind the dot, not before)