# How to instantiate guava EnumBiMap?

Tags: java, guava

Answer/Edit:

Ok, just realized I was trying to use the EnumBiMap incorrectly. I wanted a bi map that does not allow null values, which I guess the Guava library does not have. I looked at [ImmutableBiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn-history/r10/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/EnumBiMap.html) but it is supposed to be static, with non-changing values. Guess I'll just have to check for null before I put anything into a HashBiMap.

That said, this is how you can instantiate/use EnumBiMap:

Given enum:

```
enum Test{
    VAL;
}
```

Use:

```
Map<Test, Test> m = EnumBiMap.create(Test.class, Test.class);
m.put(Test.VAL, Test.VAL);
```

Or, if you want a more generic EnumBiMap, that supports any enum type:

```
Map<Enum, Enum> m = EnumBiMap.create(Enum.class, Enum.class);
m.put(Test.VAL, Test2.VAL2);
```

---

Original question:

I have looked around the [Guava API](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn-history/r10/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/EnumBiMap.html) documentation and the web, but cannot find any examples of implementing the EnumBiMap class. It doesn't behave the same as HashBiMap, which I could easily instantiate. Here is what I've tried - none of these will compile for me:

```
Map<Integer, String> m = EnumBiMap.create();
```

..similar to what is suggested here: [Java: Instantiate Google Collection's HashBiMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533513/java-)

Also tried:

```
Map<Integer, String> m = EnumBiMap.<Integer, String>create();
```

..similar to formatting here: [Google Guava: How to use ImmutableSortedMap.naturalOrder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906946/google-guava-how-to-use-immutablesortedmap-naturalorder)

And:

```
Map<Integer, String> m = EnumBiMap.create(Integer.class, String.class);
```

Has anyone successfully implemented EnumBiMap or seen any examples? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean (Guava [version 14.0](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/EnumBiMap.html)):

```
Map<Test, Test> m = EnumBiMap.create(Test.class, Test.class);
m.put(Test.VAL, Test.VAL);
```

And please notice the signature:

```
<K extends Enum<K>, V extends Enum<V>> EnumBiMap<K, V> create(Class<K> keyType, Class<V> valueType)
```

So `Integer` and `String` are not suitable for *K* or *V*.